# USB Keyboard suddenly worked wronly and unconfigured laptop keyboard and mouse

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, keyboard-layout

I've been using an external USB keyboard and mouse on a Lenovo E480 laptop for more than two years with ubuntu 19 and then 20 without any issue, a few days ago, suddenly both keyboards and mouse start behaving strangely.

**Mouse**

- If I select a portion on test in the Text Editor, for instance, then
  I am not able to unselect it by clicking outside the selected area
- If I click on the icon for an opened application without having the
  focus, it opened a new one instead to bring it to the foreground
  (like right-clicking on the icon and choosing the New Window option)

**Keyboards**

If I plugin the USB keyboard and I don't press any key on it, the laptop keyboard works properly, but at the right moment I press some key in the USB keyboard, both keyboards don't work properly anymore: letter keys appear as uppercase and numbers show special character associated (like if I press Cap Locks and the number in a keyboard working properly).

Both keyboards are Spanish and I've configured them for a long time  as Spanish layout in Setting > Region & Language > Input Sources, also there I setup Language and Formats for English (United States) without any problem.

**What I've tried**

- `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`
- upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04, and `sudo apt update`
- Changed the language from English to Spanish and the other way around and then restart the session, here it has worked for a while and randomly after plugging the USB keyboard but when I restarted the computer stopped working and the same issues as commented above.

**Update**

Base on some comments, I forgot to mention that I also tried:

- To use the previous kernel from grub > Advance Options
- To use another USB Spanish keyboard

Could someone please give any help here?

Thanks

Comment: Try other keyboard. If it work fine that there's your answer.

Comment: When you boot go to grub's Advanced Options menu and pick previous kernel version.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried my old keyboard, also a Spanish one, and the same issue

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I also tried this before